# Internal error in eclipse when running java program

Tags: java, eclipse, internal

Eclipse froze on me earlier today, so I typed "top" into the command prompt and killed it.  Now when I try to run a java application, I get this error:

```
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.debug_3.7.0.v20110509
```

That's all that shows up under details.

None of my previously working programs run, and I have no clue what this is.  I have Eclipse 1.5.0 running 1.6 and 1.7 Java, depending on what program.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you killed part of the process but not all of it. It is possible that a java process is running with a reference to this job. I would try restarting your computer to see if it will stop whatever process is referencing that jar.

Aside from a restart, then another option would be to use (in linux) pstree, filtered for your user to see if any other jobs are referencing that jar and/or java.

EDIT:
Another path is to look at log files. On linux they are in /var/log. Here's a link in that direction: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/felog.html

Comment: I've restarted twice to no avail.

Comment: Nothing else is using java or that jar either.